# I'm having issues with mod_wsgi + Django + Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

We deployed a Python 3 application in Django 2.1.2 in a Debian Stretch server. If we run `/usr/bin/python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000` into the application directory, it works correctly.

Then, we are trying to serve the application using mod_wsgi for Apache. We aren't using a virtualenv. The version of mod_wsgi we are using is 4.6.5 and the version of Apache is 2.4. But mod_wsgi + Apache is not using Django, so the index.html seems to be like this:

`{% if user.is_authenticated %} Hello {{ user.first_name }}` instead of the page with css styles, images and so on

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf` content is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername myapp
DocumentRoot /home/project/myapp/myapp/templates/myapp
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /home/project/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp
WSGIProcessGroup myapp

<Directory /home/project/myapp>
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors here.

Firstly, you should absolutely not set your DocumentRoot to the templates directory. In fact, you should not set it at all; delete that line.

Secondly, you have set your app to serve on the prefix "myapp". I doubt you wanted to do that; it sounds like you just want your app to serve on the root. So remove that from the alias:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/project/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
```

Comment: I tried that, then restarted Apache. With that Apache configuration in the sites-available file, I get this error in /var/log/apache/error.log:

`[Wed Mar 27 07:05:52.609215 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 12936:tid 140276901172992] [remote 10.52.127.195:51266] ImportError: No module named 'myapp' `

The whole error log in: pastebin.com/dJJJTUBS 

And, when I open the servers URL, I get a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.